# Making keras loss using tensorflow back-end not penalize segmentation network on unlabeled pixels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Am training a neural  network to perform image segmentation. not all parts of the image are labelled and the unlabeled parts are not consistently in the same place(ie last row or column). The unlabeled pixels have a label of -1 while the labelled are  either 0 or 1. When I calculate the binary cross entropy loss, i flatten the output then perform a standard log loss. so i was wondering if its possible in tensorflow to get the indices of the all -1 rows so that i can generate a mask to cancel the loss resulting from unlabeled parts.

Comment: Please, provide a more in-depth descrition of what your problem is and what is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_mask(labels):
    mask = tf.clip_by_value(labels, - 1, 0)
    mask = tf.ones_like(mask) - tf.abs(mask)
    return mask

def my_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    mask = make_mask(y_true)

    log_val = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    hx_0 = tf.log(log_val)
    hx_1 = tf.log(1 - log_val)
    cross_entropy = (y_true * hx_0 + (1 - y_true) * hx_1) * mask

    return tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, reduction_indices=[1]))
```

this is what I finally came up with to not penalize the segmentation model on unlabeled parts